# What tense do we use with "since"?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Consider these two sentences:

> The money has been delivered since 1st January 2000.
>
> The money was delivered since 1st January 2000.

Are both of them grammatical?

What may be the difference between them?

Comment: Both sound incorrect to me. *Since* sounds somewhat continuous: from then until now... *delivered*, a discrete event, throws me off. *It was delivered on 1/1/2000.* *It has been sitting in your account since 1/1/2000.*

Comment: @medica, But the exact date delivered is not known. The only information is that as of 1/1/2000, the money has been delivered.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Was the money delivered *before*, *on* or *after* that date?

Comment: @ClickRick, Delivered either before 1/1/2000, or on 1/1/2000. Exact date is unspecified, it could have been delivered on 1 day, 1 week, or 1 year before 1/1/2000.

Comment: So as at 1/1/2000, the money *had* been delivered. Got it.

Comment: Do you need to use since? *Our records indicate that the money was delivered on or before 1/1/2000.* It's hard to work in *since* without a continuous sense. *Our records since 1/1/2000 show the money as having been delivered.*

Comment: Perhaps *the money has been available since 1/1/2000*.

Comment: @medica, Would "as of" work instead of "since"? E.g. "We acknowledge that the money has been delivered (sent) as of  1st January 2000". The idea is this, the record only shows the received date (receiving party), not the sent date (sending party). Thus, we know that the money was received on 1st January 2000. So, it was **sent** on or before that date.

Comment: @medica, Would we use the past tense or present perfect for "as of"?

Comment: It should be *"was delivered"* if you use *"as of"*.

Comment: @PeterShor knows more than I do about this.

Comment: @PeterShor, Btw what's the explanation that present perfect isn't appropriate here? Isn't it used when the date of action is unspecified?

Comment: The trouble is not with the present perfect, but with the verb. _Deliver_ is a verb that in non-progressive forms can only carry a **punctual** meaning (the moment of delivery), whereas _since_ requires a **continuous** meaning. It _was delivered_ (point in time) on or before 1/1-2000, wherefore it _has been available_ (continued state) since 1/1-2000.

Comment: And @Janus knows more than I do about it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Interesting, it's odd that we can say "has been available" but not "has been delivered"... Seems like both of them actually describes a state, e.g. the state of "having been delivered" which is a continued state since 1/1/2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most applicable sense of *since* in those sentences is

> from a definite past time until now <sub>(source: [www.m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/since))</sub>

Sentence one, using a continuous tense to convey an action happening repeatedly over a given time frame, matches the meaning of *since* correctly, so the sentence is grammatical.  It means that some amount money was initially delivered on 1 Jan 2000, and subsequent payments of money have also been delivered regularly from that time until now.  (The interval is not specified, but payments are often scheduled weekly or monthly.)

Sentence two uses the simple past tense to denote a single action in the past; combining this with *since* is a grammatical error, because *since* requires an extended period, not a single event.

So, if money has been paid repeatedly at regular intervals starting on 1 January 2000, then sentence 1 is your correct choice.

If, on the other hand, there was only a single payment, then you do want to use the simple past as in sentence 2, and replace *since* with either *by*, *on or before*, or *no later than*.  (when used as a time reference, *by* is the same as *no later than*, as seen in definition 3b at [www.m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by).)

Comment: I disagree with your analysis of the first sentence. I immediately interpreted it to mean "The money is in the state of having been delivered ever since the 1st of January 2000." Do you have corpus evidence to back up your analysis?